# ArgumentOutOfRangeException VB

Tags: vb.net, arguments, substring

The user is supposed to write is health insurance card number in the "numero" textbox. The number is 4 letters then 8 digits (LANS10763985).
My problem is that when I left the textbox empty, my app crash!
How can I just put a MsgBox that says to enter something!!!!
Noob here sorry!

```
    Dim numero As String 'Numéro d'assurance maladie
    Dim lettre As String 'Quatre premières lettres 
    Dim chiffre1 As String 'Quatre premiers chiffres
    Dim chiffre2 As String 'Quatre derniers chiffres

    numero = txtNumero.Text
    lettre = txtNumero.Text.Substring(0, 4)
    chiffre1 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(4, 4)
    chiffre2 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(8, 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Private Sub btnResultat_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResultat.Click



    Dim numero As String 'Numéro d'assurance maladie
    Dim lettre As String 'Quatre premières lettres 
    Dim chiffre1 As String 'Quatre premiers chiffres
    Dim chiffre2 As String 'Quatre derniers chiffres

    numero = txtNumero.Text 


    If numero.Length <> 12 Then 'Verifier que le numéro a bel et bien 12 caractère
        MsgBox("Ce numéro est invalide. Veuillez inscrire quatre lettres suivi de 8 chiffres pour un total de 12 caractères")

    Else

        lettre = txtNumero.Text.Substring(0, 4)
        chiffre1 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(4, 4)
        chiffre2 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(8, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Length` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of `String`:

```
If txtNumero.Text.Length <> 12 Then
    MessageBox.Show("The number must have 12 letters, like LANS10763985")
    Return
End If

Dim numero As String 'Numéro d'assurance maladie
Dim lettre As String 'Quatre premières lettres 
Dim chiffre1 As String 'Quatre premiers chiffres
Dim chiffre2 As String 'Quatre derniers chiffres

numero = txtNumero.Text
lettre = txtNumero.Text.Substring(0, 4)
chiffre1 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(4, 4)
chiffre2 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(8, 4)
```

Additionally you could check if the chiffre are really only digits

```
If Not chiffre1.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then
    MessageBox.Show("The first chiffre must contain only digits and no letters")
    Return
ElseIf Not chiffre2.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then
    MessageBox.Show("The second chiffre must contain only digits and no letters")
    Return
End If
```

Comment: This is probably better than mine. Mine just throws a message box when it errors this does checks beforehand instead... :D

Answer (score -1):

You could use try/catch to stop the app from crashing.

```
Dim numero As String 'Numéro d'assurance maladie
Dim lettre As String 'Quatre premières lettres 
Dim chiffre1 As String 'Quatre premiers chiffres
Dim chiffre2 As String 'Quatre derniers chiffres


Try
    numero = txtNumero.Text
    lettre = txtNumero.Text.Substring(0, 4)
    chiffre1 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(4, 4)
    chiffre2 = txtNumero.Text.Substring(8, 4)
Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    MessageBox.Show("Format is incorrect!")
End Try
```

So you would "try" to get the values for numero, lettre etc. but as soon as your exception shows up it catches it and instead shows a message box.

Feel free to call me out where i'm wrong in the comments but hope this helps